# ATTiny406 | Unexpected PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) Output

Tags: arduino, pwm, atmel, attiny

We are experiencing strange PWM (analogWrite) behavior on pin PA3 of our ATTiny406 when our supply voltage exceeds ~11VDC. This pin is driving a MOSFET which controls the ground signal to the LED plane in the video below.

As you can see, we see our LEDs are fading as expected up until we reach ~11VDC. Once we exceed ~11VDC, the output faintly flashes the LEDs and it is difficult to know why. We are using the Arduino core and analogWrite(255) works fine as well as digitalWrite(ourPin, HIGH) also works fine. The issue arrises when we start trying to reduce the duty cycle < 100%.

We have tried an alternative pin, namely pin PB1 since it supports analog functionality, with the exact same results/behavior.

I have attached the schematic below. Please see the video linked below for a demonstration of the behavior.

Video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADFWE4RHylU

Schematic:

[image]

Board Layout: https://a360.co/3CdoDiY

Parts List:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16OjBE95yzUi9agkYGnmKwKylf1_NNQJW/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103941411199955966513&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Is this definitely an issue with the output from the microcontroller and not a power supply issue? What does the MOSFET gate input look like on an oscilloscope?

Comment: The non-PWM outputs behave as expected and the power supply provides the voltage and current I would expect.

Comment: Have you looked at the power rails with a scope during the bad behaviour?

Comment: Sure have - all looks as expected. There seems to be something odd happening with the PWM because that same pin behaves perfectly fine when set to a high signal.

Comment: First up, you should have pull down resistors on the mosfet gates. For the few milliseconds it takes for the micro to exit reset an execute code your gates are floating. There are also a number of issues i see - the transzorbs will turn to smoke at the slightest overload. Your circuit doesn’t anticipate a ‘load dump’. Google that one. I would suggest using a constant current led driver. This would eliminate your buck converter. The opto is useless, use a simple RC filter and a small transzorb to protect the micro inputs. Anticipate the micro failing. What is the fail strategy?

Comment: Can you communicate your layout to us by giving us the PCB coppers and wiring paths, and whether they are single-conductor or twisted-pair, how thick they are, how much loop you have for the 2+ amps you're drawing. (I'm aware of your other question). The more detail you can give us, the better chance we have to help you. My (at this point wild) guess is you've accidentally created a Joule Thief or other blocking oscillator with your wiring or layout or some other aspect of what you've got.

Comment: If it were me, I would charge a few 400F SuperCaps in series and use that as a local 5-volt or 9-volt power supply for at least the MCU and signals, but I'm just a hobbyist, so you probably also need some serious filtering. I do know the "Load Dump" @Kartman mentioned is one serious challenge, and there are others, I believe (very low voltages at times, very high voltages at times, high surges, both positive and negative, are what I assume). This is serious engineering, and serious liability if your design causes an accident (or many!) Don't guess -- **know** you're right.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD here is a link to our board: https://a360.co/3CdoDiY

Comment: @jacob80 -- Have you made any progress?

Comment: Nope - we can’t seem to get our heads around this one. Right now after a long list of suggestions here, we are on a path to rework this design unless you have any minor tweaks that could be made to make this work.